# How to prevent ffmpeg lib from printing in a command line when playing audio with a discord bot?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, pyffmpeg

I have a question about ffmpeg. I wrote a discord bot with discord.py lib, which plays audio when somebody joins a channel. I wanted the program to run on my computer in the background, so no console log will appear. Therefore I start the python script using a .bat and a .vbs file, so the process runs in the background. This works fine so far. The problem is that the ffmpeg lib (I assume it's the ffmpeg lib...) prints out a line ("[mp3 @ 0000020168869040] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate") in the command prompt when it plays audio, so everytime somebody joins a channel a command prompt appear on my desktop for 1 sec only to show this line, afterwards it closes, but it's really annoying that it shows up everytime. I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the ffmpeg lib to print out this line, but i couldnt find out how so far.
Can someone help me with that?
Thanks Cookie

my Code:

```
def getAudioSource(source):

    audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="E:/PythonPrograms/DiscordBotHallo/Dateien/ffmpeg-win64-v4.2.2.exe", source=source)
    return audio_source


def getRandomGreeting():

    list = os.listdir("E:/PythonPrograms/DiscordBotHallo/Begrüßungen")
    Greeting = list[random.randrange(len(list))]
    Greeting = "Begrüßungen/" + Greeting
    return Greeting


@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):

    if before.channel == None and member.id != 801800464756768768:
        greetingPath = getRandomGreeting()
        audio_source = getAudioSource(greetingPath)
        vc = await after.channel.connect()
        vc.play(audio_source)
        while vc.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        vc.stop()
        await vc.disconnect()
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/326629/how-can-i-make-ffmpeg-be-quieter-less-verbose) yet?